# Can I make Postgres print more lines of context for a PG::SyntaxError?

Tags: postgresql

When provisioning our database in development, we are feeding in very long SQL statements to declare numerous functions. Sometimes, we make a mistake and there is a syntax error, so we get output like this:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 14782: BEGIN
            ^
```

That's fine, and we can eventually find the problem, but it would be *really* helpful if Postgres would emit a couple of lines before and after the problem instead of *just* the line with the problem. Is it possible to configure Postgres to print more lines before and after a PG::SyntaxError?